# Trying to render Public API's content by Axios, but nothing happens

Tags: node.js, express, axios, ejs

I'm trying to render some random content of a Public API using `axios` so that every time a user clicks on the input, it'll randomly render a different cocktail name. However, whenever I click the input, it doesn't work...
Public API random: `https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api.php`.
Public API: `https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api.php`.
See the codes here:

**index.js:**

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import axios from "axios";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const API_URL = "www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php";

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
      res.render("index.ejs");
    
});

app.post("/submit", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(API_URL);
        const result = response.data;
        res.render("index.ejs", {
            drink: result[Math.floor(Math.random() * result.length)],
        }); 
        res.redirect("/");
     } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to make a request", error.message);
     } 
});



app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log(`Server is running on ${port}`);
});
```

**index.ejs:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cocktails Generator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Cocktails</h1>
    <br />

    <form action="/submit" method="post">
      <input type="submit" value="Generate Cocktail">
    </form>

<% if (locals.drink) { %>
 <div class="cocktail-box">
    <p><% drink.strDrink %></p>
  </div>

<% } %>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two main issues in your code.

Firstly, you need to put the `https` protocol on the `API_URL` like so:

```js
const API_URL = "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php";
```

Secondly the API only returns an object with one property `drinks` which is an array of only one object. That means this won't work:

```js
drink: result[Math.floor(Math.random() * result.length)]
```

You need to change it to:

```js
drink: result.drinks[0]
```